# AVAudioPlayer continues to "play" after pausing using command center

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I am setting up my iOS application to playback .mp3 files, and allow control from the command center. However, I am encountering a very strange issue with my AVAudioPlayer. I have set up a handler for the play/pause toggle event, but when I pause the player, it seems to continue "playing" in the background. If I wait a few seconds and then press play, it will jump ahead in the track as if it has been silently playing while it is paused.

Additionally, I have set up seek functionality that sets the currentTime of the player, but when I press pause, it jumps back to where it was in the file originally.

I'm completely lost as to why this is happening in either case. My only suspicion is that I am not setting up either my player or remote transport controls correctly.

I have set my project up so that a "SoundManager" singleton handles keeping track of the audio files that are currently in the queue, and exposes functions for controlling the audio. When playTrack is called, it sets up a new instance of an AVAudioPlayer with the file at the given position, then begins playback.

Code below (with irrelevant methods removed):

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer

open class SoundManager {
    private var session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    private var player: AVAudioPlayer?
    private var trackList: [String]
    private var currentPosition: Int

    static let shared = SoundManager()

    private init() {
        try? session.setCategory(.playback)
        trackList = [String]()
        currentPosition = 0
        setupRemoteTransportControls() // This method hooks into the MPRemoteCommandCenter and adds targets
    }

    func setupRemoteTransportControls() {
        // Get the shared MPRemoteCommandCenter
        let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()


        // Add handler for Play Command
        commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { [unowned self] event in
            if let player = self.player {
                if !player.isPlaying {
                    self.player?.play()
                    return .success
                }
                return .commandFailed
            }
            else{
                return .commandFailed
            }
        }

        // Add handler for Pause Command
        commandCenter.togglePlayPauseCommand.addTarget { [unowned self] event in
            if let player = self.player {
                if player.isPlaying {
                    self.player?.pause()
                    return .success
                }

                return .commandFailed
            }
            else {
                return .commandFailed
            }
        }


        // Seek
        commandCenter.changePlaybackPositionCommand.addTarget{ [unowned self] event in
            if let changePlaybackPositionCommandEvent = event as? MPChangePlaybackPositionCommandEvent {
                let time = changePlaybackPositionCommandEvent.positionTime
                self.seek(to: time)

                return .success
            }

            return .commandFailed
        }
    }

    func playTrack(atPosition: Int = 0){
        self.player?.delegate = nil
        self.player?.stop()

        let fileName = trackList[atPosition]
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "mp3")!
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

        try? session.setActive(true)
        self.player = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        self.player?.prepareToPlay()
        self.player?.play()

        refreshNowPlaying()
    }

    func refreshNowPlaying() {
        // Code removed, this just updates metadata on the lock screen
    }

    func addToTrackList(files: [String]) {
        trackList.append(contentsOf: files)
    }
}
```

Comment: Might not be relevant, but playpause is just for physical earbuds etc., for the lock screen and control center you need play and pause separately

Comment: Thanks matt, I'll switch back to that. I had them separately at first and still encountered the same issue, though.